# Using mysql from Xampp for java jdbc program

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc, connectivity, xampp

I have Xampp installed on my pc with mysql database. now i wish to use this mysql database for my java JDBC program. For that i have writen following program.

```
package mysqltype4driverdemo;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


public class MysqlType4DriverDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException {
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("user","root");
        prop.setProperty("password","");
        Driver d=new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Connection con = d.connect(url,prop);
        if(con==null)   {
            System.out.println("connection failed");
            return;
        }
        DatabaseMetaData dm =con.getMetaData();
        String dbversion=dm.getDatabaseProductVersion();
        String dbname=dm.getDatabaseProductName();
        System.out.println("name:"+dbname);
        System.out.println("version:"+dbversion);

    }
}
```

but it says "package com.mysql.jdbc" does not exists.
P.S. : i am using netbeans 7.2.x IDE on windows XP platform

Comment: Do you have that package available to the compiler and on your classpath? The answer must be no.

Comment: yes i have added it to the classpath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you might have tried putting the library on the global CLASSPATH. For Netbeans projects, that's not quite right. You need to add the appropriate library(ies) to the project using Netbeans's library facility.

1. **Right-click** on the project's root node in the *Projects* tab.
2. In the pop-up context menu, click on *Properties* (on the bottom of the menu).
3. Click on *Libraries* under ***Categories:***. You should see the following screen:
   [image: Netbeans Project Properties Dialog: Libraries]
4. Click on the *Add Library...* button.
5. Under *Global Libraries* click on *MySQL JDBC Driver* and then click the *Add Library* button.
6. Click on *OK*.

You should be good to go.

If you need a specific version of the driver, you can download it, and then after clicking on *Add Library...* you can click on *Create...* to add the downloaded version to your library repository. You'd then remove the default JDBC Driver from the project, and add the library containing the specific version.

I tried this out myself using your code and a newly-created project. No additional imports needed, and the default driver included with the Netbeans distro should be good enough unless you need a specific version for your project.

Comment: thanks @RobertB it worked well. i was unaware of this things in ide. thanks for detail explaination

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the JDBC driver for mysql from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Once you download it, add the jar to your classpath and you should be good to go.

Comment: Netbeans should already have the MySQL driver. It is included (I believe) in the Database module that is part of the base IDE. It needs to be on the project's classpath, using the library facility.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, once you have downloaded the driver, you can paste it in you java installation at ...jre\lib\ext\

Then it would be available for all your projects with the default JRE system library which you can verify when you create a new project.